# Loading jquery library and jquery scripts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have found a lot of conflicting information about this on the internet. Some sites say that Wordpress automatically loads jquery, and others say you have to load it in functions.php

I want to enqueue a script in functions.php that is dependant on jquery. I read that you have to specificy jquery as the $deps parameter

My code is:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-file', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-file.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
```

is specifying jquery in the $deps parameter enough? Will wordpress then automatically load jquery too? **Or do I actually have to enqueue jquery as a script as well?**

My code above loads "my-file.js" but the script isn't working which tells me that either jquery isn't being loaded or there is sitll a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress by default register jquery for you 
In your jquery script file, you have to use jQuery instead of $ to avoid confliction and you can enqueue your script

Answer (score 0):

dependencies: An array of handles to assets which your script or style depends on. These will be loaded before your enqueued script.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-file', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-file.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
```

Before your script jquery will load.

```
array('jquery')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition before enqueueing the script

```
if( ! wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'enqueued' ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-file', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-file.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
```

Comment: Thank you but why did you put " wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); " in an if statement?

Comment: It checks if jquery is enqueued or not, so if not  , wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); will be executed.

Comment: Thank you, will it load it in the correct order for when my scripts is dependant on jquery?

Comment: Yup, That will make sure that jquery is enqueued/loaded before your scripts if jquery hasn't enqueued yet.